# Count number of rows with distinct value in column in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

**In T-SQL, how can I query this table to show me record counts based on how many times a distinct value appears in a column?**

For example, I have a table defined as:

```
ControlSystemHierarchy
----------------------
ParentDeviceID int
ChildDeviceID int
Instrument bit
```

I want to display the number of records that match each distinct ParentDeviceID in the table so that this table

```
ParentDeviceID  | ChildDeviceID  | Instrument
1               | 1              | 0
1               | 2              | 0
1               | 2              | 1
2               | 3              | 0
```

would return

```
ParentDeviceID | Count
1              | 3
2              | 1
```

Comment: So, if you have e.g. two rows with `2,3,0` for ParentDeviceID that would result in `Count=1`?

Comment: Well when I asked this question that situation would lead to `Count=2`.  However, for the sake of learning, how would I do it so that it only counted rows that were distinct across all columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ParentDeviceID, count(*) as [Count]
from ControlSystemHierarchy
group by ParentDeviceID
```